# Which jQuery "edit-in-place" plugin do you use?

Tags: jquery

I need to implement some edit-in-place functionality for a table (where each table cell (in that row) will turn into a textbox/textarea when clicking an edit button, then when the save button is clicked, update a database and change the fields back to text.

Obviously I'll be handling the AJAX edit/update part, but what is the "best" edit-in-place jQuery plugin?

Thanks.

Comment: You should rephrase the title to something more specific, and less open ended. This is not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jeditable plugin is the best i've used:
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

Answer (score 2):

[Datatables](http://datatables.net) has an [Editable plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/)

Supports

- adding new records to the table
- selecting and deleting records
- editing cells

Comment: @Downvoter ..... care to explain why ? (granted the question is a bit vague - but whats wrong with my answer ?)

Comment: People are probably downvoting you for answering a question that should probably be closed. I know it doesn't meet the guidelines for questions, but this is the fastest way to get quick/reliable answers, so...